# Airconsole menu button hidden on iPhone X

Tags: airconsole

[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD61C.png)

Airconsole menu button hidden on iPhone X.
How can fixed this problem?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for letting us know. We will look into that issue

Answer (score 0):

We have submitted a fix to Apple and are waiting for them to accept our submission.